# I'm trying to get a next word after matching word using awk

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sh

I'm trying to get a next field after matching field using `awk`.

Is there an option to do that or do I need to scan the record into array then check each field in array and print the one after that?

```
<domain-controller>
<remote host="${jboss.domain.master.address}" port="${jboss.domain.master.port:9999}" security-realm="ManagementRealm"/>
</domain-controller></pre>
```

I want only 9999 as a output.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/master.address/)print $(i+1)}' failed
```

Comment: Why are you parsing an `XML` file with `Awk`? Why not `xmlstarlet` or `xmllint`?

Comment: if you have alternate solution , it would be helpfull

Comment: Provide the complete `XML` file from the root node

Comment: I dont have complete xml file i just got few line from sample file. I want to grep only port number 9999 as output from the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do something like this with grep:

```
grep -oP '(?<=master\.port:)\d+' file
```

Output:

```
9999
```

Of course all files must have the same structure with regards to the leading string (master.port:) for this command to work.

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate XML documents use xml parsers/tools.
Let's say you have a valid XML structure (it's enough to add opening `<pre>` tag to make your structure valid):

```
<pre>
<domain-controller>
<remote host="${jboss.domain.master.address}" port="${jboss.domain.master.port:9999}" security-realm="ManagementRealm"/>
</domain-controller></pre>
```

---

***[xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)*** solution (with *XPath* 1.0 expression):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "substring-before(substring-after(//remote/@port,':'),'}')" -n failed
```

The output:

```
9999
```

---

`substring-after(//remote/@port,':')` - to extract substring after `:` from `port` attribute value

`substring-before("9999}",'}')` - to extract port number before ending `}`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
awk '{match($0,/domain.master.port/);if(substr($0,RSTART+20,RLENGTH-15)){print substr($0,RSTART+20,RLENGTH-15)}}'  Input_file
```

I am using match keyword of awk here and matching regex there from domain.master.port then as per match function when a regex is matched then it's variables called RSTART and RLENGTH will be set and then printing them if they exist. Thus it will print the digits or 999 values if a match is found.

Comment: Thanks so mcuh :)

Comment: Glad that it helped you, you could select it as helpful answer or correct answer if you think it is.